# validar usuario

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tengo una duda tengo hecho un login pero el problema es que si un usuario no se ha logueado puede entrar en la pagina poniendo la extensión; como puedo verificar si esa persona ha iniciado sesión y si no lo ha hecho le envió al login¿?

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: ./logueado/index.php');
  }
  require 'database.php';

  if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos';

    if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
      header("Location: ./index.php");
    } else {
      $message = 'Lo siento el usuario o contraseña no existe';
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Necesitas negar el inicio de sesión quedando así if (! isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: ./logueado/index.php');
  } agrega el signo "!" antes del isset() con el cual le indicas que si no esta definida la variable sesion "user_id" entonces lo redireccione al login.

Comment: en la pagina donde el usuario entrara solo si esta logueado deberías agregar esto `if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal, quieres que, si alguien visita `/logueado/index.php` y no está logueado vuelva a la página de login, para ello lo que tienes que volver a hacer es hacer la comprobación de nuevo en las páginas donde el usuario tiene que estar registrado:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  header('Location: <ruta al login.php>');
}
```

Comment: Archangels Cuando pongo tu codigo a la hora de loguearme con usuario y contraseña correctos me lleva a la pagina de loguin en canvio si quito tu código y lo dejo como estaba me inicia sesión pero no me verifica la sesión

Comment: Necesitaría un poco más de código para estar seguro, pero intuyo que no le estás estableciendo el valor de $_SESSION['user_id'] en ningún lado. Si acaso después de revisarlo no ves el error, edita la pregunta con el código donde inicias la sesión para el usuario a ver si hay algo que pueda fallar.